# XSLT relative path

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have below xml.

```
<MpGroup>
<MpGroupItem>
        <MeasurePoints>
            <MeasurePointItem>
                <Measures>
                    <MeasureItem>
                        <Name>xyz</Name>
                        <Result>2</Result>

                    </MeasureItem>
                    <MeasureItem>
                        <Name>rty</Name>
                        <Result>2</Result>

                    </MeasureItem>
                </Measures>
                <MeasureLimit>
                    <CurveLimit>
                        <CurveLimitItem>
                            <X>1</X>
                            <Y1>1</Y1>
                            <Y2>1</Y2>
                        </CurveLimitItem>
                        <CurveLimitItem>
                            <X>2</X>
                            <Y1>1</Y1>
                            <Y2>1</Y2>
                        </CurveLimitItem>
                    </CurveLimit>

                    <CurveYUnit></CurveYUnit>
                </MeasureLimit>


            </MeasurePointItem>
        </MeasurePoints>
        <Name>ABC</Name>

 </MpGroupItem>
```

I am inside the MeasureItem and from there I need to get the value of MpGroup/MpGroupItem/Name. I don't want to use xpath. I want to use relative path like //../../../../Name.

I have below xslt code but not working.

```
                     <xsl:for-each select="MpGroups/MpGroupItem">

                    <xsl:for-each select="MeasurePoints/MeasurePointItem">
                         <xsl:if test="Measures != ''">
                            <xsl:for-each select="Measures/MeasureItem">
                                <InputValue><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//../../../../Name)"/></InputValue>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="Measures = ''">
                             <InputValue><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//../../Name)"/></InputValue>
                         </xsl:if>  


                  </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:for-each>
```

Can anyone please let me know how to  use relative path instead of xpath. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question tagged as XSLT but saying you "don't want to use xpath" to select a value does not make sense as XPath is the language used in XSLT to select values from an input XML document.

For me it sounds as if you want to navigate to `ancestor::MpGroup/MpGroupItem/Name` or more directly to `ancestor::MpGroupItem/Name` from your `MeasureItem` element(s).

Comment: Yes Martin you are right. Actually I am new to xslt. Is there any way to achieve it by using //../../../../Name something like this.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use that rather odd approach with `//../../../../Name`, what do you want to express with that? If the context is `MeasureItem` element then my two suggestions seem to do the job to navigate to respectively select the `Name` child of the `MpGroupItem` element. I have never seen anyone use `//` (which means `/descendant-or-self::node()/`) to then navigate up the parent axis four times to then access a child, if you don't want to use the ancestor axis and want to use the parent axis from your `MeasureItem` element then `../../../../Name` should do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit difficult to answer when the obvious approach is one that you say you don't want to use, without giving a reason. This means we're left wondering what your criteria are for preferring one solution over another.

Since the XML you have given us is incomplete (there's no end tag for the outermost element), perhaps you actually have more than one `MpGroupItem` in the document, and you are looking for the `Name` element in the "current" `MpGroupItem` (that is, the `MpGroupItem` container of the context item). If that's the case (and it's a wild guess), then the most appropriate XPath expression would probably be `ancestor::MpGroupItem/Name`. You could use `../../../Name` if you prefer but it's less readable and less robust. Using a `//` at the start of this path would definitely be wrong.